# How can I get rid of the original border on a label when drawing my own?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, border, custom-controls

I have created a label control that inherits from Label and allows a border to be drawn with colour and size to be applied set in properties, as long as the border style is fixed single.  This works fine except that despite drawing the new border after calling base the original border is still drawn:

[image: Label comparison]

Clearly I want to show only the new border and not the original.  Here is the code in the control:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, DisplayRectangle, _borderColor, BorderWidth,
                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, _borderColor, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, _borderColor,
                BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, _borderColor, BorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }
    }
```

And here the code to generate the two labels for comparison:

```
    private void labelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var label = new AdvancedLabel
        {
            BorderColor = Color.Yellow,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            BorderWidth = 3,
            Location = new Point(10, 10),
            Text = @"Advanced Label",
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        };

        Controls.Add(label);

        var label2 = new Label
        {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Location = new Point(10, 35),
            Text = @"Standard Label",
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        };

        Controls.Add(label2);
    }
```

So, can anyone tell me what I am missing here?  I have tried everything I can think of!!

Comment: Making default border transparent?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot set a colour or thickness on the default border, hence the need for the custom control...

Comment: Have you tried removing call of the base border draw base.OnPaint(e); ?

Comment: Yes, I have.  Unfortunately whilst it resolves the problem it also means that no text is painted amongst other handling issues.  I have also tried disabling it and manually drawing the text in OnPaint, but there does appear to be a problem with both setting the content aligment and design and runtime resizing...

The examples I have seen (e.g. MSDN) ALL use very similar code to mine, which made me think I might be missing something so obvious that they did not include it...

Comment: Why turn on the border if you don't want it??? Add your BorderColor and/or a BorderWidth as  a Property and all is well.

Comment: @TaW - I do want the border.  I do NOT want the default border.  It is not possible to set the border style to FixedSingle without getting the border, but what should happen is that the new border should overwrite the original.  This does not happen with my code or MSDN code.  I need to understand why and what I can do about it...  I do not want to add a new property as it will confuse users of the control who will expect that if they set the BorderStyle to fixed single they will get a FixedSingle border!

Comment: Well, I hope your users won't be surprised and confused by the BorderWidth property you have already added then.. If you give them good names like CustomBorderColor etc it shouldn't be too confusing.

Comment: Hopefully not, since there is no such property on a standard Label.  However, there is a BorderStyle property on Label, and it is *very* bad programming practice to break a control which is what you are effectively proposing i.e. if I did as you suggest and they set BorderStyle nothing happens so they are looking for a bug!  Remember that not everyone has intellisense and not everyone would think to look for another property with a similar name that they have no way of knowing exists when a property that they probably know about already and which should do the job does exists but is broken...